# How to convert to proper time from stat() module

Tags: perl

I have a code to retrieve last modified date from `stat()` module in Perl. But the output which displayed is not in proper time format.  Could you please help me to get proper time (`HH:MM:SS`)?

Please find the sample program I have used:

```
        my $file="filename";
        my $time=(stat($file))[9];
        say "$time";
```

Output: `149160`

Please help me convert into `HH:MM:SS`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you just want hours, minutes and seconds, you can use [POSIX](https://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX) and [gmtime](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/gmtime):

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use POSIX qw(strftime);

my $file="filename";
my $time=(stat($file))[9];
say strftime('%H:%M:%S', gmtime($time));
```

Comment: Or `localtime` instead of `gmtime` if you want to see the timestamp in local time.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you only want hours, minutes and seconds, as an alternative approach, you may use [localtime](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime) or its companion function, [gmtime](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/gmtime), without the POSIX module and simply select the desired time components.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

my $file = "filename";
my @time; 

@time = localtime((stat($file))[9]);
say join ":", @time [2,1,0];   #...HH:MM:SS in local time
@time = gmtime   ((stat($file))[9]);
say join ":", @time [2,1,0];   #...HH:MM:SS in GMT time
```